# Visual Studio - custom menu

Tags: visual-studio

I've got some powershell scripts that I need to run from time to time. I would like to have custom menu with few items where each would run some command. I also would like to have create this menu dynamically (the best - when VS run). Is it possible to achieve something like that? What should I read to achieve that? Maybe there are some external libraries which allow me to do that?

EDIT:
dynamically becouse I need some external programm to feed Visual Studio what items do I need and what script should be run.

Comment: let me know if that fits your expectations - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12244/Adding-Menu-Items-to-context-menus-inside-the-Visu   if yes I'll add it an answer

Comment: @DeJaVo yes, it looks pretty but i'm not sure if it's not too old

Comment: So please let me know if it worked for you and I'll add it as an answer for you and others...